# Hide/Unhide rows Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, show-hide

[Example spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G40nF.jpg)

Is there code to automatically hide and unhide rows after a specific cell is updated? On the example spreadsheet if I would enter "C414" on cell A9 and then the quantity on B9 it would unhide the row directly below and move focus to A10. I also want an option where if I update A3 it would clear all fields and hide all rows except for row 9. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at onEdit() in simple triggers

Comment: Do you have any code you're working on? What research you did till now?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I'm new to Google Sheets and have never worked with Javascript before.